# "Refer" Vs "Allude"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

As far as I'm concerned, both of the verbs "[refer](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/1887259)" and "[allude](https://www.google.com/search?q=allude+meaning&rlz=1CDGOYI_enTR825TR825&oq=allude+meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l3.2916j1j4&hl=en-US&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)" are used to mention something indirectly. But the question is how they differ in meaning and where I can use each one?
I have made some examples. Please have a look on them and let me know which option suits each example better and why?

> 1. Pronouns are often used to ........... to a noun that has already been mentioned.

a. refer 
b. allude

> 2. He kept ............. to his wife, but didn't mention her name.

a. alluding 
b. referring

To me, both of the choices work identically in both of the examples without any particular difference in meaning.

Answer (score 3):

### Refer can be a *direct* reference; it has multiple meanings

The verb **refer** has several meanings (or different shades of meaning).

One of these is:

> refer to [somebody/something] -- phrasal verb
>
> - B2 to talk or write about someone or something, especially in only a few words:
>
>   - *In her autobiography she occasionally refers to her unhappy schooldays.*
>   - *He always refers to the house as his "refuge".*
> - C1 If writing or information refers to someone or something, it relates to that person or thing:
>
>   - *The new salary scale only refers to company managers and directors.*
>
> --- [*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/refer-to-sb-sth)

As you can see, these are very **direct** references.

### Allusions are always indirect

Compare that with **allusion** which means something that is unsaid:

> something that is said or written that is intended to make you think of a particular thing or person:
>
> - *The film is full of allusions to Hitchcock.*
> - *Her novels are packed with literary allusions.*
>
> --- [*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/allusion)

In the examples: this means the film does not **overtly**<sup>([Definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/overtly))</sup> mention Hitchcock.

### To your question

The question is asking you to distinguish between 
- the use of the word **refer** as in **reference**,  and
- the use of the word **allude** as in **allusion**.

A reference is often quite direct, while an allusion is *indirect and unsaid*.

### A word to the wise

By the way, don't confuse "allusion" and "illusion".  Illusion<sup>([Definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/illusion))</sup> is perhaps a more common word -- they are **not** the same.

Comment: @A-friend Refer and Referring (assuming he was saying *my wife this/that*)

Comment: Well, then refer and allude.

Comment: Uh, @whiskeychief here is a conflict between your and Smock's posts! I am just interested to know why Smock thinks that in #2 "referring" sounds better and to you "alluding" works well?! Is it a matter of personal style and preference? Is it a matter of regional (BE/AE) usage? Or it is simply a matter of meaning?

Comment: Thank you again @Smock, but could you possibly tell me more about the example #2? It seems that there is a contradiction between your answer and whiskeycheif's response.

Comment: Both could be correct, but in test questions you have to pick “the best answer” in the mind of the test writer.   The fact that the speaker didn’t refer to his wife by name suggests he was alluding to her.   Your interpretation may vary.

Comment: If he says things like "My wife is great" "My wife loves comedy films" surely that is direct? Just because he's not using her name doesn't make it indirect does it? If he just said things like "we love comedy films" that would be indirect, and allude to him having a wife(/partner). *I love driving to work in my car* directly refers to having a car, *I love driving to work* alludes to having a car. Or have i got this mixed up somehow?

Answer (score 3):

1. refer - because it is mentioning it directly
2. alluding - because he doesn't mention it directly. He does not mention her name, hinting that he's talking about his wife(not naming her.)